# How can track marker clicks in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, markers

How can I view which markers are being clicked on by users in Leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

A few options

1. You could build your own server end-point that registers a new database record each time a marker is clicked, including whatever information you want to track
2. You could use Google Analytics and jQuery and do something like:

   ```
   var marker = L.marker([51.5, -0.09]).addTo(map);
   marker.on('click', function() {
      // sends notification to your Google Analytics account
      ga('send', 'event', 'marker', 'click', 'my marker');
   }
   ```

   you would need more customization than shown here to track specific markers.

   Google Analytics event tracking: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/events
3. There is a service called maptiks that was built for map tracking and analytics:
   http://get.maptiks.com/maptiks-v1
   https://www.sparkgeo.com/projects/maptiks

   I've never used this, so I can't say more than that